# Turning a list with only strings into sublists with strings and floats in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am really struggling with making a python code. Any help would be very much appreciated. The function I need to write a code for is below. Since the numbers are strings in the input, I know I can't somehow separate by name of the student, I think I must somehow convert the numbers into int/float and then somehow separate the list into sublists by name (ie. by string) but I don't know how to accomplish this. I know I can use map(int, ) to turn something into int but it doesn't seem to be working and the number of grades (ie. str i need to turn into float) can be different with any input

Thanks!

Code:

```
def string_list(L):

    '''(list of str) -> list of list
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new list of 
    lists where each inner list has the format :
    [name (str), grade, grade, grade, ...] where the name 
    is a string and the grades are floats.
    >>> string_list(['Joe, 60, 90, 80', 'Harry, 60, 70', 'Jill, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'])
    [['Joe', 60.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Harry', 60.0, 70.0], ['Jill', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
    '''
```

Comment: Try to break the problem down. You're given a big string, which contains both names and grades. How can you separate those pieces out? (Hint: Look at the format of your input strings!)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Each person's name with their grade is an individual string so I'll see if I can somehow split up each of those strings then maybe convert numbers into int from there.

Comment: For fun (and to remind you how easy we have it in Python...) I [implemented this in Haskell](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/6e129c9f015d39100ccaa4079f140f64). To be fair, I did re-implement `splitOn` and `strip` that exist in the `Data.Text` package. I intended to have no imports, but found that defining `Data.Char(isSpace)` was...tedious.

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_list(L):
    final_list = []
    for element in L:
        new_entry = element.split(',') # Split on commas; returns a list of strings
        new_entry = [x.strip() for x in new_entry] # Remove whitespace from each string in list
        new_entry[1:] = [float(x) for x in new_entry[1:]] # Cast all entries but the first to float
        final_list.append(new_entry)
    return final_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and for adding the # comments about what each line does so I know whats going on. I'll try this one out!

Comment: Thank you again for the code! Just two questions about it, when you write element.split(',') why is it splitting at commas between strings and not at commas in the string? Would it even  be possible to split at commas in the string because strings are immutable? Secondly, when you use the word 'element' could any other word have been used? To test this I put elxment instead of element and it still worked does this mean element could be any word? If it could be any word what exactly does it mean/do? Other than that I understand the rest thanks!

Comment: It is splitting at commas in the string. `element` is one element of the original list, e.g. `'Joe, 60, 90, 80'`. `element.split(',')` returns a list of strings, but they include whitespace, hence the additional `strip` command. I separated the `split` and `strip` into two lines to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Got to love the magic oneliner list comprehension!

```
[[float(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val.strip() for val in person.split(',')] for person in L]
```

*The same list comprehension but for narrow screens:*

```
 [[float(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val.strip() 
      for val in person.split(',')]  
      for person in L ]
```

## Usage

Which you could slap into your function like so:

```
def string_list(L):
    return [[float(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val.strip() for val in person.split(',')] for person in L]
```

And use it like so:

```
>>> L = ["Joe, 60, 90, 80", "Harry, 60, 70", "Jill, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98"]
>>> string_list(L)
[['Joe', 60.0, 90.0, 80.0],
 ['Harry', 60.0, 70.0],
 ['Jill', '98.5', 100.0, '95.5', 98.0]]
```

---

## Breakdown

List comprehensions are awesome but ugly! So let's decompose this behemoth into its corresponding parts:

```
for person in L]
```

For each item (e.g. `"Joe, 60, 90, 80"`) in our list

```
for val in person.split(',')
```

If we split each of those strings into a list of strings such that
`"Joe, 60, 90, 80"`-> `["Joe","60","90","80"]` and store iterate over each of those elements (`"Joe"` or `"60"` and so on) storing each of those values as `val`

```
float(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val.strip()
```

If `val` only consists of digit characters (`.isdigit()`), then convert it to a float. Otherwise, return the string (without white-space characters like space via `.strip()`)

```
[[<code> for val in person.<more>] for person in L]
```

The inner brackets group the elements of the person, without them you only get a single list of strings.

> If you wanted a single list you would need to reorder the `for <thing> in <list>`'s like so:
>
> ```
>  [float(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val.strip() 
>      for person in L
>      for val in person.split(',') ]
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and the excellent breakdown!

Comment: Thanks! The breakdown is actually reverse of the way I made it, so I thought I would show my working. Just a quick side note, one liners are awesome but not super sustainable in long term(timewise) code. For production code, you would really want to make sure the performance boost outways the complexity (to debug them).